# use getpass in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using this code:

```
import getpass

pwd = getpass.getpass(prompt = 'Please enter password:')
```

Unfortunatley I cannot enter anything in the terminal. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure. I just ran that exact code in my VS Code and it worked. I got a "Please enter password:", and then I entered 'blah' and then pwd was 'blah'. What if you try getpass.getpass(prompt='Please enter password', stream=sys.stdout) ?. Make sure to import sys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle of this function is that you can enter text as in a classic input but it is not displayed on the screen.
If you try to add `print(pwd)` and hit some keys at the time of input, it should return exactly what you typed

Comment: well I cannot enter anything. will try again

Comment: well it does actuall sorry - thanks - I just cannot copy and paste and that was the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to figure this out myself, and realised that in VS Code the prompt to enter the password appears at the top of the window, not inline as it does in Jupyter.

I found this a bit confusing coming from a Jupyter environment, so added some code to check if the user was running VS Code and display an additional message:

```py
if any(['VSCODE' in x for x in os.environ.keys()]):
   print('Please enter password in the prompt above')
```